# Is multiple enumerations separated by newline then comma always portable?

Tags: c++, c, enums, c99, c++03

Take this enum as an example to the question

```
enum
{
     one = 1
   , two = 2
   , three = 3
};
```

I've compiled this enumeration with the following compilers without issue:

- Visual Studio 2010
- IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM 6.21
- g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
- gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Is this syntax guaranteed to be supported under C99 and C++03?

With that said, I'd like to **avoid a discussion about why use this syntax**.

Comment: Short answer, yes. Preprocessor and string literals aside placement of newlines is not significant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extra whitespace or the specific choices of spaces is entirely irrelevant in the context of defining an `enum` and the enumerators are separate by comma. Thus, the quote way to define enumerators is certainly covered by the C++ standard (all versions thereof) and by C99 and later standards (I don't make any claims for C90 because I'm not sufficiently familiar with C90 and I don't have it handy but I *think* the `enum` definition works there, too). Also, in all these cases the `enum` can be anonymous.

The interesting question is support for a trailing comma after the last enumerators, e.g.

```
enum { value, };
```

which isn't covered by all standards. It is covered in C99 and later. I don't think a trailing comma is supported by C++03 but it is supported by C++11.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the trailing comma.  That issue partially inspired this question.

Answer (score 2):

The number and choice of character for whitespace between tokens doesn't matter in the C and C++ languages. So, that's exactly the same as `enum {one=1,two=2,three=3};`. The only time you need SOME whitespace is if you have two keywords with no "non-word" separators such as comma, parenthesis, colon, etc.

So yes, if that's not acceptable in a compiler, that compiler is a non-standard-conforming compiler.

Answer (score 2):

C and C++  allow you to add an arbitrary number of whitespaces and newlines between tokens.

So this is equivalent to:

```
enum
{
   one = 1,
   two = 2,
   three = 3
};
```

But of course yours has a somewhat unusual style...

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware it's unusual and up until today I'd never considered it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes  , guaranteed to be supported under C99 and C++03

```
 enum
{
     one = 1
   , two = 2
   , three = 3
};
```

is considered as same as below

```
enum
{
     one = 1 ,
     two = 2 ,
     three = 3 
};
```

or

`enum
{
     one = 1 ,
     two = 2 ,
     three = 3 
};`

Comment: multiple white-space can be used (as in for display purposes in a text editor), without any effect in the final code.